# Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-fabric

I added the following the in my project's *build.gradle* file:

```
Buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
   classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.14.3'
}
```

I addded this in the *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
   android:value="apiKeyValue"/>
```

I added this in the *build.gradle(app)* file:

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

And the following dependency:

```
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

After all this, why does not resolve the Crashlytics dependency?

Comment: remove jcenter() and keep network on please

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Upgrade your dependencies like so:

```
Buildscript {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.14.3' upgrade to the lastest version for compatibility
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
}
```

And add the following in the *build.gradle (app)* file:

```
repositories { 
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' } 
}
```

Comment: Done with dependency upgrade. But still showing same error

Comment: Avoid to share your API key in public :)

Comment: I'm glad to help you :).         If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and doing a up vote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to use 1.+ for the Fabric plugin dependency to use the latest version rather than specifying a specific version:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
```

There are detailed instructions on how to integrate Crashlytics into Android studio [here](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install).

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics Fabric.io deprecated.
use Firebase Crashlytics.